# Coding Minesweeper in Excel VBA: Mines are overlapping in same cell

Tags: excel, duplicates, minesweeper

So I'm doing a Minesweeper game for a class and everything is going fine more or less, however I had encountered a problem. Sometimes the Mines are being places in the same cell. I.e.: If i have 10 bombs sometimes 9 bombs would be displayed.

Here is my Code so far:

```
Sub Minesweeper()
Dim Mines As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim OverLap As Integer

'This is for Centering Text
For i = 8 To 15
    For j = 6 To 13
        Cells(i, j).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Next j
Next i

'This is for setting Table/Board
For i = 8 To 15
    For j = 6 To 13
        'By default all cells will = 1 until bomb is placed
        Cells(i, j).Value = 1
    Next j
Next i

'This generates certain Number of Mines
For Mines = 1 To 10
    Cells(((Int((15 - 8 + 1) * Rnd + 1)) + 7), ((Int((13 - 6 + 1) * Rnd + 1))) + 5).Value = 0
Next Mines

'This is for converting Mines to o and color change
For i = 8 To 15
    For j = 6 To 13
    If Cells(i, j).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(i, j).Value = "o"
        Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)
    ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value >= 1 Then
        Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an 'If' check of values during for Mines = 1 to 10. Declare your cell values first then check if that cell is a 1. If it is then place the 0. If it isn't then generate another random cell and recheck.

```
For Mines = 1 To 10
1
    x = Int((15 - 8 + 1) * Rnd + 1) + 7
    y = Int((13 - 6 + 1) * Rnd + 1) + 5
    If Cells(x, y).Value = 1 Then
        Cells(x, y).Value = 0
    Else:
        GoTo 1
    End If
Next Mines
```